# why when i try to install Eslint in Atom , then Atom install packeges form don't see this package?

Tags: package, eslint, atom-editor

ESlint install to user/.atom/packages. In Atom install packedes field type *linter-eslint*

I tried:

```
npm install eslint --save-dev
```

I got:

```
up to date, audited 252 packages in 3s

90 packages are looking for funding run `npm fund` for details
```

but Atom package installer don't see it

I tried:

```
 apm install linter-eslint
```

I got:

```
*TypeError: Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined
    at /snap/atom/286/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/lib/install.js:256:29
    at Request._callback (/snap/atom/286/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/lib/request.js:57:22)
    at Request.self.callback (/snap/atom/286/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/snap/atom/286/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/snap/atom/286/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)*
```

Comment: Atom reached the end of its life on December 15, 2022.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello try :

`apm install -g linter-eslint`